# How to auto restart a java application using Procrun by Exit Code

Tags: procrun

My application has a self-update feature.

It downloads a new version by itself, and when this occurrs at the end of the download process the JVM exits with code **2**.

Is possible to configure the **Procrun** to auto-restart the service if the exit code **2** occurrs ?

Comment: were you able to solve this? Basically, I needed to know if it's possible to propagate exit codes from wrapped application , back to procrun?

Comment: @tryingToLearn see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58658051/1470436

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved using another tool for running my application as a service: [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/)

With it, I register a parameter to NSSM like this:

```
nssm install my-service-name "java -jar snapshot.jar"
nssm set my-service-name AppEvents "Start/Pre" "cmd /c copy /y my-app.jar snapshot.jar"
nssm set my-service-name AppExit Default Exit
nssm set my-service-name AppExit 2 Restart
nssm set my-service-name AppDirectory "c:\path\to\my\app"
```

So, this lines will:

1. Register a windows service named `my-service-name` who launches a copy of my jar (java) application.
2. Set a parameter to `NSSM` to copy `my-app.jar` to `snapshot.jar` before start the service.
3. Set a parameter to `NSSM` to specify that, when my app terminates the default behavior is assuming that the service must stop
4. Set a parameter to `NSSM` to specify that, when my app terminates with the **exit code 2** it must be restarted (my java application) and the service must continue to running.
5. Set a parameter to `NSSM` to specify that my app will using the **current directory** as `c:\path\to\my\app`

   ---

Another solution is creating a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) to be on loop, like this (I called it `run-app.bat`):

```
@echo off
set java=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_192
:start
copy /y my-app.jar snapshot.jar
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto :run
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :end
:run
"%java%\bin\java.exe" -jar snapshot.jar --start
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :start
:end
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

And using the NSSM to register the service in a simple way:

```
nssm install my-service-name "cmd /c run-app.bat"
nssm set my-service-name AppDirectory "c:\path\to\my\app"
```

In this scenario, the NSSM will just launch my batch `run-app.bat`.
The batch will stay on loop (restarting my app) while the application exits with code `2`.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing your solution with us, however, it does not answer the original question: How to do something **using ProcRun**. Sometimes it is not possible to change to a different tool, e.g. when it is part of a larger end-to-end solution or simply because of corporate policies.